# How can I get all the modified fields before saving the editing in cake php?

Tags: entity, diff, cakephp-3.x

Using the

```
$entity->errors(); //is returning all errors.
```

to find changes before upgrading
There is something like

```
$entity = $this->Controller->patchEntity($entity , $this->request->data); 
echo $entity->diff (); // how?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for:

```
$entity->dirty()
```

If you want an array containing alla the dirty properties you can do

```
$entity->name = 'Foo';
$entity->description = 'Bar';

debug($entity->extract($entity->visibleProperties(), true));
```

you'll get

```
[
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'abbreviation' => 'Bar'
]
```

see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-has-been-modified)

Comment: To simplify I did so 

foreach($LFields as $key => $field){
                if ($cliente->dirty($key)){ .....
}

Comment: I edited my answer so you don't need to loop through the fields